# SharePoint REST API sites list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, webhooks

I'm following (https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/apis/webhooks/webhooks-reference-implementation) tutorial to integrate Sharepoint Online into our application.

The application is written using Asp.Core 2 with Sharepoint REST API because CSOM is not supported by the core.

The problem is that in the tutorial webhooks are created only for one site. 
How do I create webhooks for other sites in Sharepoint Online? How do I get a list of these sites using REST API?

Comment: Hello @Martin, Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: The only possible way to get list of sites that I have found was through search query API: _api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:\"STS_Site\"'

Answer (score 1):

As @martin mentioned in comment, you can get sites through below url:

```
your_host_name/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web'
```